# Changing the background color of AutoComplete DropDownList of TextBox

Tags: c#, controls, gdi

How can I change the background color of the autocomplete dropdown list of a textbox? I have searched a lot but have not found any proper solution. The existing solutions use a panel or some other control to mimic the behavior of autocomplete but I want to change the color of the dropdown list of textbox either by driving a class from it or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect solution for it. HERE: [Autocomplete Menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu)